# execute jquery before page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can this code run berfore page load it works after pageload

or is there any way to wait other lines of code for this part of code ?

```
  jQuery("#simulation")
        .on("pageload", ".s-d12245cc-1680-458d-89dd-4f0d7fb22724 .pageload", function(event, data) {
            
    var jEvent, jFirer, cases;
    if(data === undefined) { data = event; }
    jEvent = jimEvent(event);
    jFirer = jEvent.getEventFirer();
    if(jFirer.is("#s-Input_1")) {
      cases = [
        {
          "blocks": [
            {
              "actions": [
                {
                  "action": "jimSetValue",
                  "parameter": {
                    "variable": [ "pid" ],
                    "value":productid
                  },
                  "exectype": "serial",
                  "delay": 0
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "exectype": "serial",
          "delay": 0
        }
      ];
      event.data = data;
      jEvent.launchCases(cases);
    }
  });
```

the complete lookup file code is there:

```
(function(window, undefined) {
  var dictionary = {
    "d12245cc-1680-458d-89dd-4f0d7fb22724": "Screen 1",
    "f39803f7-df02-4169-93eb-7547fb8c961a": "Template 1",
    "bb8abf58-f55e-472d-af05-a7d1bb0cc014": "default"
  };

  var uriRE = /^(\/#)?(screens|templates|masters|scenarios)\/(.*)(\.html)?/;
  window.lookUpURL = function(fragment) {
      
       if (fragment.indexOf('?') > -1)
{

    var productid=fragment.split("?")[1].split("=")[1];


      jQuery("#simulation")
        .on("pageload", ".s-d12245cc-1680-458d-89dd-4f0d7fb22724 .pageload", function(event, data) {
            
    var jEvent, jFirer, cases;
    if(data === undefined) { data = event; }
    jEvent = jimEvent(event);
    jFirer = jEvent.getEventFirer();
    if(jFirer.is("#s-Input_1")) {
      cases = [
        {
          "blocks": [
            {
              "actions": [
                {
                  "action": "jimSetValue",
                  "parameter": {
                    "variable": [ "pid" ],
                    "value":productid
                  },
                  "exectype": "serial",
                  "delay": 0
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "exectype": "serial",
          "delay": 0
        }
      ];
      event.data = data;
      jEvent.launchCases(cases);
    }
  });
  
 fragment="screens/d12245cc-1680-458d-89dd-4f0d7fb22724";
}
    var matches = uriRE.exec(fragment || "") || [],
        folder = matches[2] || "",
        canvas = matches[3] || "",
        name, url;
    if(dictionary.hasOwnProperty(canvas)) { /* search by name */
      url = folder + "/" + canvas;
    }
    return url;
  };

  window.lookUpName = function(fragment) {
    var matches = uriRE.exec(fragment || "") || [],
        folder = matches[2] || "",
        canvas = matches[3] || "",
        name, canvasName;
    if(dictionary.hasOwnProperty(canvas)) { /* search by name */
      canvasName = dictionary[canvas];
    }
    return canvasName;
  };
})(window);
```

Comment: You cannot run JS code that interacts with the DOM before the DOM has loaded.

Comment: if the page is not loaded, how can you get the `#simulation` element?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the entire body, and reveal it once the script is done.

CSS:

```
html { visibility:hidden; }
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Your code
  document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
});
```

Comment: the problem is not about html loading i want to wait all code to this code run not at same time